# NodeJS writable streams: how to wait for data to be flushed?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a simple situation in which an `https.get` pipes its response stream into a file stream created with `fs.createWriteStream`, something like this:

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('some-file');

var downloadComplete = function() {
  // check file size with fs.stat
};

https.get(options, function(response) {
  file.on('finish', downloadComplete);
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Almost all the time this works fine and the file size determined in `downloadComplete` is what is expected. Every so often however, it's a bit too small, almost like the underlying `file` stream hasn't written to the disk even though it has raised the `finish` event.

Does anyone know what's happening here, or have any particular way to make this safer to delays in `finish` being called and the underlying data being written to disk?

Comment: Any particular reason you've added the event listener inside the `https.get`'s callback?

Comment: [From the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish), the event should be fired when the data has been flushed to the disk… but [this issue](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/6438) says the opposite. You should chip in there

Comment: Also, can you provide a minimum example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Try this syntax `response.pipe(file).on('close', downloadComplete)`. Pipe will automatically end the stream, then you simply listen for the `'close'` event i.e. when the file descriptor has been closed. I am not sure this is the problem, but you can try it and see if it works for you